# Is public Consumer<KTable<String, String>> consumer() {...} valid spring scs definition for Kafka Ktable?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to create binder with spring scs Kstream with method signature as
public Consumer<KTable<String, String>> consumer() {...}

if fails with error below:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199 cannot be cast to class org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199 and org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

can we create binder with Ktable?

it works if we pass Kstream
public Consumer<Kstream<String, String>> consumer() {...}

Comment: Unclear what Consumer class you've imported

Comment: it's java.util.Function for spring-cloud-stream consumer binding